# Double coset ring in Ihara's paper

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, ring-theory

[image]
I was reading *On discrete subgroups of the two by two projective
linear group over $\mathfrak{p}$ -adic fields* by Ihara, and I would like know why the set $\lbrace Ug :g \in G_l\rbrace$ has $q^l-q^{l-1}$  elements.

First the definition of double coset ring it's not clear to me. The only reference that I found about this is in *Some properties of group-theoretical categories* and it's below.

Therefore I could think for example that in (1) what matter is know how many elements in the basis of $\mathcal{R}(G,H)$ there are in LH and RH, so as $G_1=\cup U\pi_i$, for some finite representatives $\pi_i \in G_1$ (there are $q+1$), in this manner he have that $G_1^2$ has $(q+1)^2$ summands, finally since $(q+1)U$ are $q+1$ summands then $G_2 $ has $q^2+q$ and then this is its number of representatives mod $U$.

However this is assuming that when we do it the multiplication with elements in the basis (in $G_1^2$) give us other element in the basis? what is the right argument?

[image: Double coset ring]

Comment: Please do not use images to convey critical mathematical information not otherwise present in your post. [This explains why](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).